# "This post appears to be a duplicate of" when actually not duplicate despite extremely similar wording

Tags: discussion, bug

I asked a [question about a human language](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/android-tts-for-thai-language).
And now I want to ask the same kind of question, about another human language.
So I tried to post a similar question (just replacing "Thai" with "Mandarin Chinese" in title and body).

Even though these 2 questions are extremely similar in wording, they are about a completely different topic, will interest different people, and will receive different answers.

**PROBLEM:** I can't post my second question, I am told:

> This post appears to be a duplicate of [...]

It prevents the question from getting posted.
I have a reputation of 3,451 on that site if that matters.

Should I try to [circumvent](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7591/android-tts-for-mandarin-chinese-language) the check, or should I just restrain myself from asking?

Comment: Can you edit this post to include the wording of your second question, please?

Comment: @AnnaLear: I added a link to the actual question and a sentence (3rd line) describing what words were different in the question I tried to post. Is it enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of...just kidding

Comment: I'm not sure how else this situation could possibly come up except via a resource request question. SR.SE is, so far as I know, the lone site that finds those acceptable. I'd say just use some different wording.